# Convert HTML to PDF api

Tags: php, html, pdf, converters, pastebin

pastebin/TxJ6YbSU

I have this HTML and need to convert it to PDF, I have used many libraries PHP but nothing works right, when the images appear the html is bugged or when the html is perfect the images do not appear being absolta or relative to the urls ... Somebody help me please, my client can not afford a lib that does this and I do not know what else to do

Comment: Hi - you can post Portugese language questions on the Portugese site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ You'll get more answers on this site if you write in English. Thanks!

Comment: Only english questions on this site.

Comment: I change the text to english, thanks for the alert